# creating an envelope icon and its link on html code

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I successfully added my LinkedIn, Github accounts to my webpage but couldn't do the same for my Gmail account. Do you know what I am missing here? I think I am picking the wrong class combination:

```
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/.../" target="_blank" class="icon brands fa-linkedin"><span class="label">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
<li><a href="https://github.com/..." target="_blank" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
<li><a href="https://medium.com/@..." target="_blank" class="icon brands fa-medium"><span class="label">Medium</span></a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:...@gmail.com" target="_blank" class="fa fa-envelope-o"><span class="icons">email</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to (Open envelopes): far fa-envelope-open

or: fas fa-envelope-open

Closed envelopes:

fas fa-envelope

far fa-envelope